# Flutter manage dx of Offset by swiping to right or left

Tags: flutter

in Flutter application i want to divide width of screen to 10 part and when user swipe to right or left i could detect each part of this swipe, for example

after divide screen to 10 part i have a variable named `screenParts` as double which that has `0.0` by default, when user swipe to right the variable value should be plus 1 part and swipe to left should be minus the variable value minus

this variable value should be `between 0.0 and 1`, you could consider `Tween<double>`

```
double screenParts = 0.0;
final double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 10;
```

i want to use this value inside into this part of code:

```
return GestureDetector(
  onPanUpdate: (details) {
    if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
      if (screenParts / screenWidth == 0) screenParts = screenParts += 0.1;
    } else if (details.delta.dx < 0) {
      if (screenParts / screenWidth == 0) screenParts = screenParts -= 0.1;
    }
    setState(() {});
  },
  child: SafeArea(
    child: FadeTransition(
      opacity: CurvedAnimation(parent: animation, curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn),
      child: SlideTransition(
          position: Tween<Offset>(
            begin: animateDirection,
            end: Offset(screenParts, 0), //<---- this part
          ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
            parent: animation,
            curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
          )),
          // ignore: void_checks
          child: Material(elevation: 8.0, child: child)),
    ),
  ),
);
```

it means i try to manage `dx` of `Offset` by `screenParts` value with swiping to right or left

Comment: The question is not legible. Please try to improve upon your explanation using legible English. Would be happy to help once the details are understandable  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]
is this what you are looking for?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: MyHomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  double position = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void handleXChange(double deltaX) {
    setState(() {
      position = deltaX / MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(position.toString()),
        DragArea(
          handleXChange: handleXChange,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class DragArea extends StatefulWidget {
  const DragArea({Key key, @required this.handleXChange}) : super(key: key);

  final void Function(double newX) handleXChange;

  @override
  _DragAreaState createState() => _DragAreaState();
}

class _DragAreaState extends State<DragArea> {
  double initX;

  void onPanStart(DragStartDetails details) {
    initX = details.globalPosition.dx;
  }

  void onPanUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    var x = details.globalPosition.dx;
    var deltaX = x - initX;
    widget.handleXChange(deltaX);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onPanStart: onPanStart,
      onPanUpdate: onPanUpdate,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how can change `GestureDetector` to right or left horizontal?

Comment: @DolDurma Try `onHorizontalDragStart` and `onHorizontalDragUpdate`.

Comment: @HugoPassos with them `onPanEnd` doesn't work to release